# Using polyglossia inside a class creates error when compiling with make4ht

Tags: polyglossia, make4ht

When I set `polyglossia` as a required package in my class, the following error arises when compiling with `make4ht`:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontspec-xetex.4ht  23       Undefined control sequence.
```

In the `.log` is written the following error message:

```
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/fontspec-xetex.4ht
version 2021-09-28-22:56
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fontspec_ht_scripts
l.23 ...{\typeout{use block #1}\xeuniuseblock{#1}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Here are the example class:

```
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2021/10/23]
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ExecuteOptions{}
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
```

and a the `.tex`file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Note that, by loading the `polyglossia` inside the `.tex` file, no error is generated.

Comment: I don't get any error for these test files, which is strange, because I experienced similar issues with your class few months ago. It is possible that it was fixed by the `make4ht` update, as it now loads `.4ht` files in classes. Do you have the latest `make4ht` update installed?

Comment: I've also tried with ```make4ht``` version v0.3j from CTAN.

Comment: and what is the exact command you use? I've tried both `-l` and `-x` options and they seem to work.

Comment: Using the ```-x``` option. Although there are those error messages, the ```html``` is generated. Using the ```-l``` option, the messages are gone but still got this message: ```attempt to call a nil value (field 'exit_status')```.

Comment: Ah, if you get `exit_status` error, then you may have older version of `make4ht` installed somewhere on your system. Or some other issue with the installation. I had to deal with this issue few months ago, but it should be fixed now.

Comment: Right, @michal.h21! I've just installed vanilla texlive. Now the error is gone. ;-)

Comment: Ah, that's great!